# Connecting to MySQL via Python and I have contradictory results

Tags: mysql, pythonanywhere, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database hosted on Python Anywhere. In the below example `connection.get_server_info()` returns a result however `connection.is_connected()` returns `False` and I am unsure why.

Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
import sshtunnel

sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
    ssh_username='USERNAME', ssh_password='PASSWORD',
    remote_bind_address=('USERNAME.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com', 3306)
) as tunnel:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        user='USERNAME', password='DB_PASSWORD',
        host='127.0.0.1', port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
        database='USERNAME$default',
    )
db_info = connection.get_server_info()
if connection.is_connected():      
    print('Connected to MySQL DB...version on ', db_info)
else:
    print('Failed to connect.')
print(db_info)
connection.close()
```

I have a paid account on Python Anywhere so SSH tunneling should be possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to access the SSH tunnel after it has been closed; the tunnel is closed when you exit the `with` block, so anything that uses the connection needs to be indented so that it is contained within it.  Your code above look like this:

```
import mysql.connector
import sshtunnel

sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
    ssh_username='USERNAME', ssh_password='PASSWORD',
    remote_bind_address=('USERNAME.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com', 3306)
) as tunnel:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        user='USERNAME', password='DB_PASSWORD',
        host='127.0.0.1', port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
        database='USERNAME$default',
    )
    db_info = connection.get_server_info()
    if connection.is_connected():      
        print('Connected to MySQL DB...version on ', db_info)
    else:
        print('Failed to connect.')
    print(db_info)
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Thank you Giles! Relieved to see it is something so simple